# how can a derived class function call a function of the base class?

Tags: c++

Derived class function cannot access even the public members of the base class when the access specifier is private. But how is it that the function '`xyz`' of my derived class able to call '`showofb`'?
I even tried it by calling the function '`showofb`' in the constructor of C. In both cases it works.
How is it able to call the function '`showofb`' ?

```
class B  
{  
    public:  
    B()  
    {  
        cout<<":B:"<<endl;  
    }  
    void showofb()  
    {  
        cout<<"show of b"<<endl;  
    }  
};

class C : private B  
{
public:  
   C()  
   {  
        cout<<":C:"<<endl;  
   }  
   void xyz()  
   {  
        showofb();  
   }  
};  

int main()  
{  
    C c1;  
    c1.xyz();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B::showofb()` is a public function. So it can be called by `C`. If you modify `B` to make `showofb` private, `C` will no longer be able to call it.

The private inheritance means that all public and protected members of `B` are inherited as private by `C`. So `C` can still call public and protected members of `B`, but any classes derived from `C` will not be able to call members of `B`.

Comment: @Praetorian-thank you very much. Your answer helped me to sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

Private inheritance inherits the public members of the parent as the private members of the child. A class can call its own or inherited private members.

Consider this:

```
class B  
{  
    public:  
    B()  
    {  
        cout<<":B:"<<endl;  
    }  
    void showofb()  
    {  
        cout<<"show of b"<<endl;  
    }  
};  
class C : private B  
{
public:  
C()  {}
};  
class D : public B
{
 public:
    D(){};
}
int main()  
{  
    C c1;  
    c1.showofb();  // WONT WORK
    D d1;
    d1.showofb();  // WILL WORK
}
```

Comment: @littleadv-i get your point. main being a non-member function, `c1.showofb();` wont work. But it should not be able to call even in a member function right...like `xyz();` in my case. How is it possible?

Comment: @user1001204 `xyz()` is a public member of `C`, why wouldn't you be able to call it from `main()`?

Answer (score 0):

user1001204, you appear to have a mistaken concept of private inheritance. That class `C` inherits from class `B` via private inheritance means that the inheritance relationship is hidden to anything that uses class `C`. Private inheritance does not hide the inheritance relationship inside Class `C` itself.

Comment: @David-oh m sorry but if thats the case can you please explain to me what it means by -member functions of the derived class cannot access public members' ?

Comment: @user1001204 - If you derive class Z from class C - **derived class Z** will not have the access to `showofb`. Because its private in C.